# How to cancel delay before taking picture on Open Camera app?

Tags: applications, camera

I am using Open Camera (latest version), and there is a delay of about ten seconds between pushing the button and the picture being taken. I also noticed that the flash is pulsing during those 10 seconds.

Of course, I have checked the settings and set "delay" to "none", but still this behavior persists.

Before I uninstall & re-install, wiping my settings, which I am loth to do, does anyone of any other setting which that might be causing this?

Comment: Set the timer to Off. You can save the settings by going to settings manager option and restore them later. From the settings manager, you can also reset the settings directly.

Comment: Did you not read my question? `Of course, I have checked the settings and set "delay" to "none"`

Comment: Is there such a thing as "Voice Commands" activated on the app? Maybe waiting for a trigger word like "Smile", "Cheese", etc. and failing out to normal button operation?

Comment: I like your thinking (+1).  I went through all settings, including advance settings and could not find anything like that :-(